# Calling a Promise Method from another Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldapjs

Hope everyone of you are doing well. I am stuck in a bit of problem. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I am using ldapJS and I want to call another promise from searchEntry method of LDAPJS. When i write the code same as below. it throws an error

```
exports.getADUsers = async (reqst, resp, next) => {
    let flag = false;
    var finalList = [];
    let adConnStatus = await ConnectAD()
        .then().catch((errConnStatus) => {
            console.log("Error in connection with Active directory " + errConnStatus);
        });

    if (adConnStatus.status == 0) {
        let client = adConnStatus.client;
        const opts = {
            filter: '(ObjectClass=*)',
            scope: 'sub',
            attributes: ['cn', 'sid', "objectSid"]
        };
        client.search('dc=domain,dc=com', opts, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error: " + err);
            } else {
                res.on('searchEntry', (entry) => {
                    finalList = await searchEntry(entry);
                });
                res.on('searchReference', (referral) => {
                    console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
                });
                res.on('error', (err) => {
                    console.error('error: ' + err.message);
                });
                res.on('end', (result) => {
                    resp.send(finalList);
                    console.log(result);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
finalList = await searchEntry(entry);
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Please help! how to call another promise from one promise. Though the method is async why it shows this message? what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After adding the keyword `async` as suggested by `@Punth`. Also modifying a bit of the code. my new code is as follows.

```
exports.getADUsers = async (reqst, resp, next) => {
    let adConnStatus = await ConnectAD()
        .then().catch((errConnStatus) => {
            console.log("Error in connection with Active directory " + errConnStatus);
        });

    if (adConnStatus.status == 0) {
        var adUsersList = [];
        let client = adConnStatus.client;
        const opts = {
            filter: '(ObjectClass=*)',
            scope: 'sub',
            attributes: ['cn', 'sid', "objectSid"]
        };
        client.search('dc=domain,dc=com', opts, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error: " + err);
            } else {
                res.on('searchEntry', async (entry) => {
                    var raw = entry.raw;
                    if (raw.objectSid != "undefined" && raw.objectSid != null && entry.object.cn != null && entry.object.cn != "undefined") {
                        let userData = {
                            "Name": entry.object.cn,
                            "SSID": sidBufferToString(raw.objectSid)
                        }
                        var lmn = await ConnectAndGetUsersList(userData.SSID);
                        userData["XYZ"] = lmn.xyz;
                        userData["ABC"] = lmn.abc;
                        adUsersList.push(userData);
                    }
                });
                res.on('searchReference', (referral) => {
                    console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
                });
                res.on('error',  (err) => {
                    console.error('error: ' + err.message);
                });
                res.on('end', (result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    resp.send(adUsersList);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

By running the above code it doesn't shows me anything. `res.on('end' ....)` is called prior to `res.on("searchEntry"....)` Therefore the array of `adUsersList` is null.

Now my question is how to `resp.send` the final arraylist???

Comment: `(err, res) => {…}` and `(entry) => { … }` are **not** `async`  methods

Comment: How many `searchEntry` events do you expect from the response stream?

Comment: Yep, your `client.search` is not an async method so you can't use await inside. just do `searchEntry(entry).then(...)`

Comment: @Bergi Search entry events may differ from 100s to millions

Comment: @Bergi then how to make it work smoothly? What is the proposed solution?

Comment: @AdityaParab that won't show any positivity cause the promise state is still pending. using then() won't impact.

Comment: @AsadMehmood If there are so many events, `finalList = await searchEntry(entry);` and `resp.send(finalList);` doesn't make sense - `finalList` is meant to be a list (an array)?

Comment: @Bergi thats what I am asking, how to return the fulfilled promise?

Comment: @AsadMehmood But that's the wrong question: there isn't just one fulfilled promise, there are many

Comment: @Bergi can you please help in how to overcome this issue of await is only valid in async method. oh! wait let me update my question i forgot to add search entry method part

Comment: I would probably suggest something like `res.on('searchEntry', entry => { promiseList.push(searchEntry(entry)); });` with `res.on('end', result => { console.log(result); Promise.all(promiseList).then(finalList => resp.send(finalList)); });`. However, depending on what `searchEntry` does, you might need to account for backpressure and error handling.

Answer (score -1):

Update this line as follows, to invoke promises using `async/await` syntax inside a callback you need to make it async

```
 res.on('searchEntry', async (entry) => {
   finalList = await searchEntry(entry);
 });
```

Comment: Please add a comment explaining why the answer was downvoted. It would be useful for me and the community. I'm open to know and learn the missing pieces.

Comment: @PunithK Look at how the `finalList` variable is used and you'll realise that this code won't actually work

Comment: @Bergi yes, you are right, I didn't look into the whole code and I was trying to solve the error that he was pointed at. I read your comments, I agree.

Comment: @PunithK Thanks you! that solved my issue but there is another problem `res.on('end', () => { // some code})` is called prior to `searchEntry`. I tried to put `async` but did not worked! Do you have any idea as how to solve it?

Comment: @AsadMehmood You must have a clear mental model on how the event loop works in NodeJS. Event `end` is fired synchronously while you are still performing the async action on `SearchEntry`. One probable solution would be to broadcast the `end` event when you are done resolving all the promises inside `searchEntry`. Otherwise, you can follow the solution @Bergi offered above using `Promise.all()`